# Spring Data MongoDB : how to partially map domain object to MongoDB?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data

Let's say we have four fields in a Java domain object.

Instead of mapping all fields into the MongoDB document, are there ways to selectively map three fields to the MongoDB?

```
public class Person {

  @Id 
  private String id;
  private String name;

  // we don't want to map this field into MongoDB
  private String noMongoDB.

  // getters and setters
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`org.springframework.data.annotation.Transient` is for you.

The same premise as it is with the same annotation from JPA.

```
public class Person {

  @Id 
  private String id;

  private String name;

  @Transient
  private String noMongoDB.

}
```